# C++ stl error because of missing const

Tags: c++, stl, constants

i just corrected a mistake but I don't understand why. It is the const. 
The right version:

```
#include<iostream>
template <typename T>
T square(T x)
{
    return x*x;
}

template <typename T>
class BoVector{
    T arr[1000];
    int size;
public:
    BoVector():size(0){}
    void push(T x) {arr[size]=x;size++;}
    T get(int i) const {return arr[i];}
    int getSize() const {return size;}
    void print() const {for (int i=0; i< size; i++) std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
BoVector<T> operator*(const BoVector<T>& rhs1, const BoVector<T>& rhs2){
    BoVector<T> ret;
    for(int i=0; i<rhs1.getSize(); i++){
        ret.push(rhs1.get(i) * rhs2.get(i));
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
//std::cout << square<int>(5) << std::endl;
BoVector<int> bv;
bv.push(2);
bv.push(4);
bv.push(5);
bv.push(100);
//bv.print();
BoVector<int> bv2;
bv2=square(bv);
bv2.print();
}
```

The mistakes I made were that in class BoVector, I didn't have a const for the member functions:

```
T get(int i) {return arr[i];}
    int getSize()  {return size;}
    void print() {for (int i=0; i< size; i++) std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;}
};
```

using const and & is just new to me. could anyone tell me why const is necessary here?

Comment: `rhs1` and `rhs2` are passed as const so you cannot call a non const function on a const object.

Comment: because you can't call a non-`const` method on a `const` object. btw, why do you call poor left-hand side `rhs1`?

Comment: thank you! So is it a good thing to do to define as many const member functions as possible to avoid this type of error? I mean to be safe, if a function doesn't change any property of the class, then I should define it as const?

Comment: @daydayup yes, generally any member function that need not mutate the object should be marked as `const`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant. lol I should change it to lhs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `getsize` in `operator*` on a `const` parameter, you must then specify that this method doesn't change the object's state. So it is necessary to qualify the method as a `const` method: a method that it is safe to call on a const object (an object that has a *const* state).

```
int getsize() const {…}
```

It is a best practice to qualify such every method that doesn't change object's state; *i.e.* `print`and `get`.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
BoVector<T> operator*(const BoVector<T>& rhs1, const BoVector<T>& rhs2){
    BoVector<T> ret;
    for(int i=0; i<rhs1.getSize(); i++){
```

Here the parameter `rhs1` is const, so you can only call const member functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

`BoVector::operator*` has `const BoVector&`s `rhs1` and `rhs2` as arguments. Hence, you cannot call a non-`const` member function on them, i.e., all the member functions you invoke on either `rhs1` and `rhs2` should be `const`. So you will run into errors if either `getSize()` or `get()` are not `const`.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined operator to work with const:

```
BoVector<T> operator*(const BoVector<T>& rhs1, const BoVector<T>& rhs2){
```